# How to run a query in every 5 minute in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to run a query in every 5 minutes. I am wondering if there is something like a timer exists in SQL Server.

It would be really helpful for me. I googled a lot but i didn't get anything helpful.

Your suggestions would be much appreciated. 
Pooja

Comment: search for SQL Agent jobs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a SQL Agent Job via the gui or using these stored procedures: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx

Also check this example (borrowed from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/ ) :

```
USE msdb
go
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_add_job_quick] 
@job nvarchar(128),
@mycommand nvarchar(max), 
@servername nvarchar(28),
@startdate nvarchar(8),
@starttime nvarchar(8)
as
--Add a job
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = @job ;
--Add a job step named process step. This step runs the stored procedure
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = @job,
    @step_name = N'process step',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = @mycommand
--Schedule the job at a specified date and time
exec sp_add_jobschedule @job_name = @job,
@name = 'MySchedule',
@freq_type=1,
@active_start_date = @startdate,
@active_start_time = @starttime
-- Add the job to the SQL Server Server
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name =  @job,
    @server_name = @servername


exec dbo.sp_add_job_quick 
@job = 'myjob', -- The job name
@mycommand = 'sp_who', -- The T-SQL command to run in the step
@servername = 'serverName', -- SQL Server name. If running localy, you can use @servername=@@Servername
@startdate = '20130829', -- The date August 29th, 2013
@starttime = '160000' -- The time, 16:00:00
```

Comment: Just to add, You must have SQL Standard edition or higher (SQL Jobs are not available for SQL Express edition).

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file and use windows scheduler to trigger it every five minutes.
Or write a service in .Net

Comment: Hi @Nishant, thanlks for your reply . i am following this method. i need to create lock on a table . Can you help in this. i have searched a lot but i failed to get anything useful.i basically need a query which will lock a table in sql server and prevent it to be get accessed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Working with SQL-Server Agent job
2. Maintenance plan
3. Windows job scheduler
4. Trick for run on SSMS query windows (Not recommend for production or main plan)

If you need run a simple query on SSMS you can use `WAITFOR DELAY` statement

for example:

```
Declare @a int = 0
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
  -- Example code
  EXEC sp_WhoIsActive -- You can write you query or code

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'
  IF @a = 10
     Break;
  SET @a = @a + 1
END
```

Parameter @a is important for count of running. limit to 10 running in this query., or this query run untiled, your session is open. when you close session or stop running this query is stop to work.

This is not a best practice, and use for typical trick on work. for testing, check results... this is not idea for production long time